# Problem to recover effective rights on a shared folder

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to recover the effective rights on a shared folder. To do that I used the methods CreateFile, GetSecurityInfo and GetEffectiveRightsFromAclA. The problem is that when I test the rights it does not work while I set the SID of the administrator. Does this come from a bad implementation of my code? I specify that I have the rights to the file.

```
    //stringName is the file path
    HANDLE file = CreateFile(stringName.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, 
    FILE_SHARE_READ, 
    nullptr, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, nullptr);
    PSID pSid;
    //The SID is that of the administrator 
    ConvertStringSidToSidA(stringSid.c_str(), &pSid);

    PACL ppDacl;
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR ppSecurityDescriptor;
    GetSecurityInfo(file, SE_FILE_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, nullptr, 
    &pSid, &ppDacl, nullptr, &ppSecurityDescriptor);

    ACCESS_MASK pAccesMask;
    TRUSTEE_A pTrustee;
    GetEffectiveRightsFromAclA(ppDacl, &pTrustee, &pAccesMask);
    //here conditions are not respected
    if((pAccesMask & GENERIC_READ) == GENERIC_READ)
    {
        std::cout<<"ok"<<std::endl;
    }
    if((pAccesMask & GENERIC_WRITE) == GENERIC_WRITE)
    {
        std::cout<<"ok"<<std::endl;
    }
    if((pAccesMask & GENERIC_EXECUTE) == GENERIC_EXECUTE)
    {
        std::cout<<"ok"<<std::endl;
    }
    if((pAccesMask & GENERIC_ALL) == GENERIC_ALL)
    {
        std::cout<<"ok"<<std::endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before use the `pAccesMask` value make sure the [`GetEffectiveRightsFromAclA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-geteffectiverightsfromacla#return-value) function return ERROR_SUCCESS.

And because [a Windows file object maps the GENERIC_READ bit to the READ_CONTROL and SYNCHRONIZE standard access rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthz/generic-access-rights). So change the condition check logic for GENERIC_READ like this:

```
if ((pAccesMask & READ_CONTROL) == READ_CONTROL && (pAccesMask & SYNCHRONIZE) == SYNCHRONIZE) //GENERIC_READ
{
    std::cout << "GENERIC_READ" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I must add the variable (pAccesMask & SYNCHRONIZE) everytime ?

Comment: @Tom13000 You can check the definitions of [standard access rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthz/standard-access-rights) and add what you need and care.